# Why image is not being displayed in the PDF file?

Tags: database, laravel, image, pdf

I am trying to display book data - title, author, publisher and so on, plus image as a cover page. All of the data except the image I managed to display.

Here is my code:

Routes:

```
Route::get('/dynamic_pdf', 'DynamicPDFController@index');
Route::get('/dynamic_pdf/pdf', 'DynamicPDFController@pdf');
```

Controller:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use PDF;


class DynamicPDFController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $book_data = $this->get_book_data();
        return view('dynamic_pdf')->with('book_data',$book_data);
    }

    //get book data method
    public function get_book_data(){
        $book_data = DB::table('books')
                            ->limit(515)
                            ->get();
        return $book_data;
    }

    public function pdf(){
        
            PDF::setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled'=>true, 'isRemoteEnabled'=>true]);
        $pdf= \App::make('dompdf.wrapper'); //uses a method of dompdf
        $pdf->loadHTML($this->convert_book_data_to_html());// converts book data to html
        return $pdf->stream();//makes it able to show pdf file
    }

    function convert_book_data_to_html()
    {
        
     $book_data = $this->get_book_data();
     $output = '
     <h3 align="center">Book Data</h3>
     <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px;">
      <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="20%">Cover</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="30%">Title</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="15%">Author</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="15%">Publisher</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="20%">Year</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="20%">Description</th>
   </tr>
     ';  
     foreach($book_data as $book)
     {
      $output .= '
      <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;"> <img src="/storage/public/cover_images/'. $book->image .'"> </td>
     
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'. $book->title.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'. $book->author.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'. $book->publisher.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'. $book->year.'</td>
       <td style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;">'. $book->description.'</td>
      </tr>
     
      ';
     }
     $output .= '</table>';
     return $output;
    }
}
```

View:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Laravel - How to Generate Dynamic PDF from HTML using DomPDF</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   .box{
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">Welcome to our pdf data</h3><br />
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7" align="right">
     <h4>Books Data</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" align="right">
     <a href="{{ url('dynamic_pdf/pdf') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Convert into PDF</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Cover</th>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>Author</th>
       <th>Publisher</th>
       <th>Year</th>
       <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     @foreach($book_data as $book)
      <tr>
       <td> <img src="{{asset('/storage/public/cover_images/'.$book->image )}}" style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;"></td>
       <td>{{ $book->title }}</td>
       <td>{{ $book->author }}</td>
       <td>{{ $book->publisher }}</td>
       <td>{{ $book->year }}</td>
       <td>{{ $book->description }}</td>
      </tr>
     @endforeach
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: Example]

The images from the view I can display but when I click the button to convert to PDF the images are not displayed but it says image not found or type unknown.
I really do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: Where is your image location ? in `storage/public/cover_images/` or in `public/cover_images/`

Comment: storage/public/cover_images

Comment: In the convert book data to html, inside foreach loop you need to provide full path of image

Comment: Well, haven't I?

Comment: '/storage/public/cover_images/'.$book->image is not a full path

Comment: Man, thanks. It was one / before storage that I had and it caused the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Congrats man, you've got solution